# Draw Navigation Drawer underneath main bar

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

Im trying to create an app but I am stuck on something. I made a new application with Navigation Drawer as main activity. When I open the drawer is looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHmNf.png) however I want it to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhzoN.png) so it still shows the top bar. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `NavigationView` add this:

```
 android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: That would make it the correct size but it would still make the background darker. What I am trying to accomplish is something like this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template/master/screenshots/screenshot1.gif

Comment: To fix this you have to change your view hierarchy. That is, you have to nest the drawer layout below the action bar.

Comment: The problem is that the toolbar is in a different file by default and I don't know how the change the hierarchy between the files.

Comment: Oke I just copied the files from one file and nested it into the other one and it looks like its working now. Thanks!